# Hibernate mapping to store custom object as a String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create mapping that will store my custom object as a String to a single column in a database table.

**Article.java**

```
@Entity
public class Article {

    @Getter @Setter
    @Embedded
    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    @Convert(converter = LocalizedFieldConverter.class,
        attributeName = "name")
    private LocalizedField name = new LocalizedField();

    @Getter @Setter
    @Embedded
    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    @Convert(converter = LocalizedFieldConverter.class,
        attributeName = "description")
    private LocalizedField description = new LocalizedField();

}
```

**LocalizedField.java**

```
@Embeddable @Getter @Setter
public class LocalizedField {

    // map key is "en-US", value is a translation
    private Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

}
```

**LocalizedFieldConverter.java**

```
@Converter
public class LocalizedFieldConverter
    implements AttributeConverter<LocalizedField, String>, Serializable
{

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalizedField attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) { return null; }
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(attribute);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) { return null; }
    }

    @Override
    public LocalizedField convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) { return null; }
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(dbData, typeReference());
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) { return null; }
    }

    private static final TypeReference<LocalizedField> typeReference() {
        return new TypeReference<>() { /* */ };
    }

}
```

When Hibernate tries to create the database, I get this one:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: article, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(data)]

I don't want to use `@ElementCollection` as this would create additional table in my database.

---

Next try was to change mapping to this:

**Article.java**

```
@Getter @Setter
private LocalizedField name = new LocalizedField();
```

**LocalizedField.java**

```
@Convert(converter = LocalizedFieldMapConverter.class)
private Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
```

**LocalizedFieldMapConverter.java**

```
@Converter
public class LocalizedFieldMapConverter
    implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String>, Serializable {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, String> attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) { return null; }
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(attribute);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) { return null; }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) { return null; }
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(dbData, typeReference());
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) { return null; }
    }

    private static final TypeReference<Map<String, String>> typeReference() {
        return new TypeReference<>() { /* */ };
    }

}
```

In second case I had to remove `description` property from entity because database column gets a name `data` which is a name of Map inside `LocalizedField` class.

In the final I would like to have more than one `LocalizedField` property handled by the same `@Converter` (of course, if possible).

But in cotrary to first attempt, at least I get column stored as expected, in JSON format but it's named `data` instead of `name`:

```
{
    "hr-HR" : "Sončnica & vitamin E šampon za kosu i tijelo 1000 ml",
    "en-US" : "Sunflower & Vitamin E Hair & Body Shampoo 1000 ml",
    "sr-RS" : "Сончница & витамин Е шампон за косу и тело 1000 мл"
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well, if you want to store it as a string, why use @Embedded?

Comment: @crizzis When I remove `@Embedded` I get the same exception:
`org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: article, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(data)]`

Answer (score 1):

Just drop `@Embedded`, `@Embeddable`, and `attributeName` from the original solution:

```
@Entity
public class Article {

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private LocalizedField name = new LocalizedField();

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private LocalizedField description = new LocalizedField();

}

@Getter @Setter
public class LocalizedField {

    private Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

}

@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class LocalizedFieldConverter { ... }
```

`@Embedded` and `@AttributeConverter` are mutually exclusive. You're getting a `MappingException` because Hibernate cannot figure out how the hell it's supposed to map `LocalizedField` as an embeddable, since `data` itself doesn't have an attribute converter.

**EDIT** Since your `AttributeConverter` applies to `LocalizedField`, and **NOT** to `AttributeConverter.data` directly, you want:

```
@Converter
public class LocalizedFieldMapConverter
    implements AttributeConverter<LocalizedField, String>, Serializable {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalizedField attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) { return null; }
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(attribute.getData());
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) { return null; }
    }

    @Override
    public LocalizedField convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) { return null; }
        try {
            Map<String, String> data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(dbData, typeReference());
LocalizedField result = new LocalizedField();
result.setData(data); // or add an @AllArgsConstructor and use it
return result;
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) { return null; }
    }

    private static final TypeReference<Map<String, String>> typeReference() {
        return new TypeReference<>() { /* */ };
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the extra `LocalizedField` class for any other purpose, just use:

```
@Entity
public class Article {

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    @Convert(converter = LocalizedFieldConverter.class)
    private Map<String, String> name = new HashMap<>();

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    @Convert(converter = LocalizedFieldConverter.class)
    private Map<String, String> description = new HashMap<>();

}
```

Comment: Been there before at some moment. This one wraps JSON with 'data' which is some kind of overhead:
`{ "data" : { "hr-HR" : "Tekoče milo Lemon Grass 1000 ml", "en-US" : "Liquid Hand Wash Lemon Grass 1000 ml", "sr-RS" : "Tekoče milo Lemon Grass 1000 ml" } }`.
Yesterday I found working solution which is not so pretty as yours is, but column contents are exactly as expected: `{ "hr-HR" : "Tekoče milo Lemon Grass 1000 ml", "en-US" : "Liquid Hand Wash Lemon Grass 1000 ml", "sr-RS" : "Tekoče milo Lemon Grass 1000 ml" }`

Comment: Also spent few hours yesterday because I forgot to remove `@Embeddable` and was getting whole lot of exceptions.

Comment: Well, if you're serializing `LocalizedField`, then of course the resulting JSON is going to have `LocalizedField` properties, and that includes `data`. You need to be serializing the value of `LocalizedField.data` instead. See my updated answer.

Comment: (also note the use of `@Converter(autoApply=true)` in the updated answer, which makes it even less verbose)

Comment: Been here too yesterday, trying to manage map only by getting a map from Localized 
Field. I mean for 3 days I was combining all possible that came to my mind and I had pretty clear idea what exactly I want to achieve... (continuing in next comment)

Comment: The thing is I wanted to avoid putting Map directly into entity because class `LocalizedField` has many ways to set and get data from its own Map. For example I have `put( Locale local, String translation )' and alslo `put( String locle, String translation )' each used from another part of application. Having Map put directly into entiry I have to create another utility class to get all and I'm definitely more happy to have `name.put("en-US", "Now it works")` better than `LocalizeFieldUtil.put( name, "en-US", "Now it works" )` Hope you understand my point of view.

Comment: Fair enough, I only posted that option as an alternative. I believe my modified answer should still work for you

Comment: One more thing is that having `LocalizedField` as a class holding its data, I am able to write unit test for all edge cases to be sure it works as expected. For example, I have one more feature - when you set translation to "en-US", if you have locale "en-GB" it is populated with the same data automatically and so and so. And that's all packed in the single class avoiding having utility classes somewher in the app.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works with more than one LocalizedField properties needs use of `@AttributeOverride`.

Changes are:

**Article.java**

```
@Getter @Setter
@Embedded
@AttributeOverride(
    name = "data", // refers to Map name inside LocalizedField
    column = @Column(
        name = "name", // column name to use for converted LocalizedField
        columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
)
private LocalizedField name = new LocalizedField();

@Getter @Setter
@Embedded
@AttributeOverride(
    name = "data", // refers to Map name inside LocalizedField
    column = @Column(
        name = "description", // column name to use for converted LocalizedField
        columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
)
private LocalizedField description = new LocalizedField();
```

**LocalizedField.java**

```
@Convert(converter = LocalizedFieldMapConverter.class)
private Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
```